# python - How can I create dataframes looping through two parameters and then using a further loop(s) to define variable(s)

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, nested-loops

I have 6 CSV files: equivalent data for 2 TV channels **(C and B)**, each in 3 different regions **(UK, GAS, MENAT)**.

I'd like to create a series of loops that creates 6 dataframes for these CSV files by first looping through the channel and then looping through the 3 regions, to create e.g. dfCUK, dfBUK, dfCGAS, dfBGAS etc

I'd then like a further loop within this if possible, that then creates variables **(MoM, WoW)** based on data within each CSV file, just performing simple calculations using iloc or loc.

I've done the above in a very roundabout, repetitive and manual way, but have had a lot of trouble trying to translate it into a much neater series of for loops because of the various datatypes.

How can nested loops be used to achieve the above? Seems very doable but I'm very new to all of this and have had no luck trying to adapt the guidance I've found online for this purpose.

Here's vaguely what I'm going for but am probably way off the mark:

```py
    channels = ['C', 'B']
    regions = ['UK', 'GAS', 'MENAT']
    variables = ['MoM','WoW']
    
    for ch in channels:
        for reg in regions:
            dfchregions = pd.read_csv (r'C:/x/y/reg_ch.csv')
            for var in variables:
                chregvar = "{:.0%}".format(dfchregions['var'].iloc[1]/dfchregions['var'].iloc[2]-1)
```

**Here's an example of the CSV data:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CHsu.png)

**And here's an example of the resulting dataframe (though I'm not too concerned about how this will look)**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMYKm.png)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) Help us to help you and improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks

Comment: Hey thanks for this - I've added what I hope will suffice as a minimal, reproducible example

Comment: Can you provide data samples from the csv files and an example of what the output dataframe should look like?

Comment: Thanks, I've added those now - does that help?